# xpath assertion for consistent units in column width in the CALS table model

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath, docbook

i am playing with a XML Schema 1.1 based markup language which will be a very restricted subset of the DocBook vocabulary. It contains the CALS table model. Tables have column specifications with columns widths in the colspec/@colwidth attribute. A sequence of colspec elements is allowed in the Table definition. The width of a column can be defined in a variety of units, e. g, 15mm or 10* (the latter is a proportional width).

I'd like to code an xs:assertion which checks whether the units of all colspecs have the same units for column widths. For example:

- The result for the sequence *10mm,20mm,30mm* should be true. There is only one absolute unit (mm).
- The result for the sequence *10mm,2cm,30mm* should be false. There are two absolute, but different units (mm, cm).
- The result for the sequence *10mm,2*,30mm* should be false. There are two units (mm, *), so that absolute and proportional is mixed up. This is worse than the two different, but absolute units above.

Dont'know how to achieve this. If i could tokenize the column widths value, the something like *count(distinct-values(for $w in @colwidth return the-unit-of($w))) eq 1*.

But how can i code the function *the-unit-of()*? XPath function *fn:tokenize* requires a pattern, which seems to be unavailable in this case.

Any Ideas?

Frank Steimke

Comment: Isn't the unit all characters except digits (and possibly decimal separator)?

Comment: True. And this is indeed the solution: i can use the fn:translate function to filter out the digits and the decimal separator, so that only characters will remain. Thank you very much for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Based on the suggestion from michael.hor257k, this assertion at the table/tgroup element works:

```
<xs:assert test="
        count(distinct-values(for $unit in sd:colspec/@colwidth
        return
           translate($unit, '0123456789\.', ''))) eq 1"/>
```

The type of the colwidth attribute is (im my XSD Schema) a restriction of xs:token with regex=\d+(.\d+)?(*|[c|m]m|in).

The fn:translate function maps the Digits and the Decimal separator from @colwidth value to the empty string, so that only the unit remains (*10mm* becomes *mm*, *10** becomes ***). Assertion fails if there is not exactly one unit in the sequence of distinct units.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Another way of expressing the assertion, which might be a little bit more efficient (depending of course on the implementation) would be

```
every $c in xx/@colwidth satisfies f:unit($c) eq f:unit(xx[1]/@colwidth)
```

With Saxon, an advantage of writing assertions using "every ..." is that when the assertion isn't satisfied, the diagnostics tell you which $c is the culprit.

As for the question, you could implement `f:unit($x)` simply as `translate($x, '0123456789.', '')`, or if you prefer, as `replace($x, '[0-9\.]', '')`